# Creating a UI with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, xml-parsing

Is there a way to create a UI NOT on a browser with JSON data? Possibly without downloading anything either?

I have typescript code (written to parse XML data) and JSON as the output file and need a UI to display the data with certain formatting (I was thinking with HTML?).

Please let me know if this is possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat broad, but If I understand it correctly... a solution like [electronJS](https://www.electronjs.org/) should do the trick. Otherwise you could also run NodeJS locally and have it parse the XML data and "render" it to an HTML file.

edit: both solutions allow you to use XML, JSON, Typescript and/or HTML.